# How to build argsecondmax in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, argmax

In Numpy, [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) is already defined, but I need argsecondmax, which is basically the second maxima. How can I do this, I'm a bit confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finding `Nth` largest indices**

An efficient one could use [`np.argparition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) that skips sorting and simply parititions, which when sliced would give us the required indices. We would also generalize it to find `Nth` largest one along a specified axis or a *global* one (similar to `ndarray.argmax()`), like so -

```
def argNmax(a, N, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        return np.argpartition(a.ravel(), -N)[-N]
    else:
        return np.take(np.argpartition(a, -N, axis=axis), -N, axis=axis)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [66]: a
Out[66]: 
array([[908, 770, 258, 534],
       [399, 376, 808, 750],
       [655, 654, 825, 355]])

In [67]: argNmax(a, N=2, axis=0)
Out[67]: array([2, 2, 1, 0])

In [68]: argNmax(a, N=2, axis=1)
Out[68]: array([1, 3, 0])

In [69]: argNmax(a, N=2) # global second largest index
Out[69]: 10
```

**Finding `Nth` smallest indices**

Extending this to find the `Nth` smallest one along an axis or *globally*, we would have -

```
def argNmin(a, N, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        return np.argpartition(a.ravel(), N-1)[N-1]
    else:
        return np.take(np.argpartition(a, N-1, axis=axis), N-1, axis=axis)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[908, 770, 258, 534],
       [399, 376, 808, 750],
       [655, 654, 825, 355]])

In [106]: argNmin(a, N=2, axis=0)
Out[106]: array([2, 2, 1, 0])

In [107]: argNmin(a, N=2, axis=1)
Out[107]: array([3, 0, 1])

In [108]: argNmin(a, N=2)
Out[108]: 11
```

---

**Timings**

To give a perspective on the benefit on using `argpartition` over actual sorting with `argsort` as shown in [`@pythonic833's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832368/3293881), here's a quick runtime test on the global argmax version -

```
In [70]: a = np.random.randint(0,99999,(1000,1000))

In [72]: %timeit np.argsort(a)[-2] # @pythonic833's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 40.6 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit argNmax(a, N=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: this is a great answer and since it's the most efficient one it should be accepted as correct

Answer (score 3):

you can use `np.argsort` to do so

```
test =np.random.randint(1,5,10)
```

Output

```
array([3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3])
```

to get the second maximum we do

```
test[np.argsort(test)[-2]]
```

`np.argsort` sorts in ascending order, so for the maximum we take the last value, for the second maximum take the second last.

Edit: In order to improve this answer I write a function similar to the one Divakar (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832435/9534390) provided.

```
def argNmax(a, N, axis=None):
    return np.take(np.argsort(a, axis=axis), -N)
```